Enable data version control using RDS + Spring
My team is currently developing a solution using Spring and RDS to store/display our data in relational SQL table. What our customer want is to be able to retrieve the data that is in a particular time instead of just the current data, aka data version control. Is there any mechanism in RDS or other AWS service that allow us to implement that?
Thanks
